# How to load an obj file with mtl file and texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I'm trying to load an obj file that contains also a texture (jpg) and a mtl file. For now all what I found is OBJLoader, but it just loads the geometry, ignoring the texture and the mtl file. Is there already a script to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an OBJMTLLoader Script, too! Just use this one ;)

Comment: What is about them? The texture path are specified in the MTL-file which is an ordinary pure text ASCII file format. Just place the textures where you want them to be and adjusted naming and path to your needs if you don't have a modelling package like blender or 3dsMax at your hands where you could define the paths inside there.

Comment: Maybe post some source code ;) 
Are you getting some errors in the browser console about missing textures?
btw. have you checked the OBJMTL - Example that comes with Three.js?